# Fractions are converted to sup and sub elements

Tags: markdown, hugo

I'm learning Hugo and so far everything works quite fine. Now I've tried to get some content up and running and am stumbling with a strange behavior in the Markdown parser.

For a CV page I am using dates in the form of `10/2009`. While this works fine for dates which start with a 0 (like `06/2006` for example), for dates that start with a 1 (`10/2010`) the Markdown parser seems to be flawed.

My Markdown looks like this:
`**10/2009 bis 04/2013 | Bergische Universität Wuppertal**`

And the output like this:
[image]

HTML for that part is:
`<strong><sup>10</sup>⁄<sub>2009</sub> bis 04/2013 | Bergische Universität Wuppertal</strong>`

As far as I understand my Markdown should be fine and valid.

I have already dug a bit deeper into this and found that this behavior is not specific to date-like numbers, but to all numbers where 2 digits are followed by a flash and one or more digits. So 44/9 is broken in my Hugo, too.

The Markdown parser here at SO seems to work fine:
**10/2009 bis 04/2013 | Bergische Universität Wuppertal**

Any ideas on why this happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

The integrated "BlackFriday" Markdown parser is by default set to use "smart fractions" to convert fraction-like pieces of Markdown into a mathematically well-formed fraction for display purposes.

This behavior can be changed in the Hugo config files like this:

`[blackfriday]
fractions = false`

While this default behavior might be a good idea, you should have a look at the different "smart" functions of the parser and check whether you want them active or not as they might interfere with your content.

The documentation has a chapter about this: [Configure BlackFriday Markdown Rendering](https://gohugo.io/content-management/formats/#configure-blackfriday-markdown-rendering)

Comment: That is definitely non-standard behavior for a Markdown parser. I didn't know such a feature was offered by any, let alone by default.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts. Did not yet experience anything like this with any other Markdown parsers.